# jquery autocomplete is now working properly

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on **jquery autocomplete** in **mvc** platform. Now, my question is that in some textbox data autocomplete is **working properly** while in some textbox data autocomplete is **not working properly**.

For more clear, lets see the image of autocomplete task

[image]

now as per the image when I write the **R** word, I am getting the suggestion list of related **R** word.

[image]

now as per the second image I have written the whole word but still suggestion is not display.

Here is my code,

**View**

```
<input type="text" id="CustomerName" name="CustomerName" required data-provide="typeahead" class="typeahead search-query form-control autocomplete" 

placeholder="Customer Name" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ServiceJob/CustomerSerchAutoComplete",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            minLength: 2,
            multiple: true,
            success: function (data) {                    
                /*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
                    //autocomplete(document.getElementById("CustomerName"), data.data);
                $('#CustomerName').autocomplete({ source: data.data, minLength: 2, multiple: true }); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CustomerSerchAutoComplete()
{
    var customers = _Db.Ledger.Where(x => x.LedgerTypeId == (int)LedgerType.Customer).ToList();
    var result = (from n in customers
                  select new
                  {
                      kk = n.Name.ToUpper()
                  }).ToList();

    return Json(new { data = result });
}
```

Comment: whats the console log for the second image?

Comment: **autocomplete.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined**

The above statement is showing console log.
But this statement is showing for both the image.

Comment: @karan Can you try setting the minimum length property for the auto complete like: `.autocomplete({
      source: data.data,
      minLength: 2,
      multiple: true
    });`

Comment: @Rahatur by adding your code it showing me console error. i.e. **Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined**

Comment: @karan did you write that code within the `success: function (data)` function of the ajax call?

Comment: @Rahatur now I did the code within the success portion. But now in console log showing the error i.e. **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function**

Comment: @karan you have to use my sample code in context of an object. Notice the dot (.) in my sample code.

Comment: `success: function (data) {                
 /*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
 $('#CustomerName').autocomplete({ source: data.data, minLength: 2, multiple: true });
}`

Comment: @Rahatur I have edited the code as per you given. Please review it. Still it showing the same error in console log i.e. **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function**

Comment: You are using jquery autocomplete which was already working for you right?

Comment: @Rahatur yes right

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

For this error you should check that `data` is not null.

```
 success: function (data) {                
                 if(data != null)
                   {
                    autocomplete(document.getElementById("CustomerName"), data.data);
                   }
                }
```

Comment: The `data` in his query is not null as he already have the auto complete working. He has a different question. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Sorry, but your code is not working. Showing the same error i.e. **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined**